# 2.3 Api android can't work

Tags: java, android, api, google-play

i have done an android app to target 4.1 API , but when i uses it for 2.3 API i'm getting much much error !

so i want to work around these error to publish same app for only 2.3 API Devices on Google play , how to do it ? and it's possible to fix that error ?

```
    [2013-08-30 13:24:10 - SAMS] Error in an XML file: aborting build.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size      0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] W/ResourceType(18388): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-xhdpi\activity_classtable.xml:254: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle').
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-xhdpi\activity_classtable.xml:261: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle').
  [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-xhdpi\activity_classtable.xml:269: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle').
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-mdpi\activity_contactus.xml:69: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'spinnerMode' in package 'android'
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-xhdpi\activity_contactus.xml:73: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'spinnerStyle' with value '@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown').
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-mdpi\activity_setting.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'spinnerStyle' with value '@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown').
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-xhdpi\rep2.xml:2: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'columnCount' in package 'android'
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-xhdpi\rep2.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_row' in package 'android'
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\layout-xhdpi\special_spinner_dropdown.xml:1: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'textIsSelectable' in package 'android'
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\about.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\aboutus.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\admin_login.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
   [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\alarm.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\alarm_receiver.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\classtable.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\contactus.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\dash_board.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
    [2013-08-30 13:24:33 - SAMS] C:\Users\pc\workspace\SAMS\res\menu\list.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
```

Comment: Show us the code where the error is thrown.

Comment: all R  in all classes that is contain content layout not working , once change API to 4.1 every thing working OK

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its likely due to you using resources that are only in the 4.1 API and not in 2.3.

Obviously if you are using new resources or API code, such as the buttonBarStyle, this won't be available in earlier versions. I think the earliest buttonBarStyle was available was Honeycomb which was version 3.

In order to make your app compatible, you would need to do checks within your code so that it uses  the right API for the API that is being used.

In your example of the resources not being available, the easiest thing to do would be to create layouts based on the API versions.

In your standard layout folder you contain the layouts for the API that you are currently targeting, but you create layout folder for the older API levels where you are using stuff that isn't available.

For example, to create your layout for Android 2.3, create a folder /res/layout-v9 and create an xml file, of the same name as in your layout folder and recreate the design to suit the older API.

The layout within the v9 folder will automatically be used for 2.3 devices. It does depend on what 2.3 version you are using. E.g. 2.3-2.3.2 is API level 9 and 2.3.3 to 2.3.7 is API level 10 you just need to ensure the file name matches.

For example, in your `/res/layout` folder you have the design of your main activity called main_activity.xml which will make use of the new resources and designs available in version Android 4 and above (Ice Cream Sandwich and above).

In your `res/layout-v9` folder you have the design of your main activity, still called, main_activity.xml which will make use of the older API resources.

Regarding java code,  you would need to do checks to see which version you are running, and if the API level is below a certain value, e.g. before version 4, run the old API code, otherwise run the new API code.

To get the current SDK version that your app is running on use the following.

```
int apiLevel = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
```

To get the API level for a specific android version use below as an example

```
int apiLevelForVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH
```

Therefore in order to check which code to run, i.e. the new API version code or the old API code you could do something like the following

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
{
    //Run API code which is in Ice cream sandwich above
}
else
{
    //Use older version API code to ensure backward compatibility with older devices running old Android version
}
```

For information about the various android versions and what their API level is refer to http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

Hope this helps

Comment: nice answer , but after createing V9 layout .. how to make it runs automatic only with only api2.3 devices ?

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the following specific issue:

android-apt-compiler: [] W/ResourceType(37145): ResXMLTree_node header size 0x2 is too small.

None of the changes I made to my manifest, or code in general made any difference. What I located, which Android Developer Studio didn't flag was an errant character in the strings.xml file.

In between 2 string definitions there was a dash character ('-'). This was the cause of that issue in my case.

In my manifest I had a minimum API level of 14 with a target of 18. Nothing below 14 is being supported.

Comment: My problem was an ampersand character '&' in my strings.xml file. All & characters should be replaced with the value "&amp;".